# List exploration via backtracking & mutual recursion

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to implement an exploration algorithm using backtracking.  The aim is to find what might be called 'chains' within words using two rules:

- if X is selected, then so are all other instances of X

  - e.g. from `[a,b,b,a,b]` we need `[a,_,_,b,_]`
- if Y is selected, so is Y's 'opposite' - i.e. the one at the equi-distant from the end.

  - e.g. with `[a,c,c,c,b]` we take `[a,_,_,_,b]`

and so together abyxzbzxxcb would first select ab...b...cb.

- a is chosen because it the head
- by rule 2 the last b is chosen
- by rule 1, the first b is chosen
- by rule 2, the c is chosen
- as there are no other c's, the code should reapply rule 1 to get the middle b, from which no further moves are possible.

My idea is to use mutual recursion with 2 predicates:

- `find_another`: that finds another element with the same letter;
- `find_palindrome`: that picks the element equi-distant from the end.

I'm testing this with `find_loop([a,b,y,x,z,b,z,x,x,c,b],Loop).` and am failing to pick up the middle `(5,b)`, and to stop after the first result.  I think it is not correctly backtracking in `find_another` to keep looking for more `b`s, and I fear that even if it did, I would lose part of my Hist(ory) along the way.

Perhaps a better approach is to use a `findall` in `find_another`, and then pass each result to `find_palindrome`, but I thought I might be able to do everything via backtracking.

```
find_loop(Word, Loop) :-
    zip(Word, 0, WZ),
    length(Word, WL), Word_length is WL - 1,
    [X|_] = WZ,
    find_another(X, Word_length, WZ, [X], Loop).    
/*
Get a element with same letter
  if not in history, explore further via its palindrome
  else search for existing element's palindrome
*/
find_another((N,L), Word_length, Word, Hist_in, Hist_out) :-
    member((X,L), Word),
    (
    \+ member((X,L), Hist_in),
    find_another((N_palindrome,X), Word_length, Word, [(N_palindrome,X)| Hist_in], Hist_out)
    ;
    find_palindrome((N,L), Word_length, Word, Hist_in, Hist_out)
    ).

/*
Finds the palindrome element, and then looks for others with new letter
*/
find_palindrome((N,L), Word_length, Word, Hist_in, Hist_out) :-
    N_palindrome is Word_length - N,
    member((N_palindrome,X), Word),         
    (
        \+ member((N_palindrome,X), Hist_in) ->    
            Hist_next = [(N_palindrome,X)| Hist_in],
            find_another((N_palindrome,X), Word_length, Word, Hist_next, Hist_out)
        ;
            Hist_out = Hist_in
    ).

%% [a,b,c,...] becomes [(0,a),(1,b),...]
zip([], _, []).
zip([H | T], C, [(C,H)|Z] ) :-
    C1 is C + 1,
    zip(T,C1,Z).
```

Comment: I might be a little daft, but I'm not sure what the stated rules mean. In the first, *If an X is in the list, then so are all other Xs*, what does "other Xs" really mean? Can you give an example? The second rule misuses the term "palindrome". A "palindrome" would be a list where, for every i-th element out of `N` elements, list[i] equals list[N-i-1] (if I use a C-ish notation). So the second rule sounds like it's defining a list which is a palindrome, but it's a little obscure.

Comment: You are write about Palindrome but I hoped that it figuratively gave the idea of 'equi-distant from other end'

Comment: I think I understand the equidistant from the other end idea, but that seems then like rule 2 just defines an entire palindrome (*i.e.*, if a list complies with rule 2, it's a palindrome). So I am still not sure I understand the rules.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I am still not quite sure why mutual recursion did not work, but I think I can see that backtracking is supposed to delete parts of the history (which I actually needed to keep), so backtracking was the wrong way to approach this problem. With that in mind, I made it conceptually simpler by having find_another get all the other elements with same letter and then recurse over the list.  And that delivered the right solution. Hopefully I can generalise my learnings here to avoid this mistake again! ;-)

```
find_another((_,L), Word_length, Word, Hist_in, Hist_out) :-
    findall((N1,L), member((N1,L), Word), Others),
    find_another_from_list(Others, Word_length, Word, Hist_in, Hist_out).

find_another_from_list([], _, _, Hist_out, Hist_out).
find_another_from_list([H|T], Word_length, Word, Hist_in, Hist_out) :-
    find_palindrome(H, Word_length, Word, Hist_in, Hist_tmp),
    find_another_from_list(T, Word_length, Word, Hist_tmp, Hist_out).
```